# Develop in Access 2019, decompile with Access365 on customer laptop: Error "Failed to perform save operation"

Tags: ms-access, 32-bit

I am developing an A2019 application (32-bit). I then copy the completed *.accdb to the customer laptop which has A365 (32-bit) installed.

Compact and repair on the customer laptop I have tried several times, always ends with error messages like:

**"The save operation could not be performed".**

Creating the *.accde does not work then either.

I created a bat file for decompile:

```
"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.Desktop.Access_16010.9226.2114.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "J:\blablabla\IHS_ABR_A2019.accdb" /decompile
```

but the Access window does not open at all, only very briefly the DOS prompt. I found the path to MSACCESS.EXE for the A365 version, so it should fit. I can't find any instructions for this decompile command for A365 version anywhere on the net.

Any tips? thx

Comment: My suggestion would be to decompile the accdb on *your* system before deploying it to the customer's system. That way, you basically ship the (compatible) source code rather than the (theoretically compatible, but sometimes incompatible) binary code. In addition it might be a good idea to compare the build numbers of your Access 2019 and the customer's Access 365 and ensure that your system is always *older* than the customer's. (As part of our build workflow, we compile+decompile+compact our application with Access 2010(!) before deployment to ensure that it contains nothing "too new"...

Comment: ...for the customer's system.)

Answer (score 0):

As I was a participant of the AccessDevCon a few weeks ago, I tried the tool "CARDA Database Tools" on the target laptop. And everything works fine again.

What irritated me was that after every big change to the frontend I click the ribbon button Compact&Repair and see how it reduces the *.accdb size about 10% - so far so good and known.

But after I tried the "CARDA Database Tools" for the first time, the *.accdb size reduced by about 25%. This means for me that the Ribbon-Button Compact&Repair apparently does not perform the compact optimally, but with the CARDA-Tool it does.

regards